# Why are proofs written in first person plural? Were they ever written differently?

Tags: proof-writing, math-history

It's probably a silly question but it interests me when was the convention of writing proofs in first person plural introduced?

Are here any historical examples of a different POV for proof writing?

Comment: I rather like the first person plural. It is inclusive of the reader, and I think it facilitates the readers' participation, sort of like a "team" effort.

Comment: I don't think it's a convention. The teacher, speaker, or author is addressing the students, pupils, readers, or audience, who are participating in the demonstration. It comes on naturally.

Comment: I'm just glad that, in mathematics, we tend to write in the active - rather than passive - voice. This is unlike many of the other sciences.

Comment: Euclid seems to have written very "unpersonally" in his Elements, except sometimes adding "I say/claim".

Comment: Writing impersonally also comes on naturally, since the teacher, speaker, or author is describing a process (succession of operations).

Comment: Hodges writes in the preface of [_Model theory_]: ‘I’ means I, ‘we’ means we.

Comment: The best reason for using "we" is that it is shorter than "one".

Comment: I agree with amWhy, Lucian and Daniel, but I love to think sometimes when I write a proof that I am the King of the World and use the royal "we"...this thought fades away pretty soon, though.... *sigh* ...

Comment: @DonAntonio We are not amused. (but I am)

Comment: We understand thou, sir @DanielRust ... off with his head!

Comment: An example to the contrary is by Bargman. He wrote a very impacting 100+ page paper by himself in which he exclusively used first person singular over plural. It was a very jarring aspect of the paper.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From what I could gather from some google searches ([1](http://wac.colostate.edu/atd/articles/thonney2013.cfm), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24629/use-of-i-we-and-the-passive-voice-in-a-scientific-thesis), [3-pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/turnerw/Writing/writing.pdf&ei=PdipUsvPJ4PlyQGbnICoAg&usg=AFQjCNHvATfxL1NHjOm_9Uuq-l53jeC31g&sig2=EG94FjbNyYqhu4fW313eTw), and [Krantz](http://books.google.com/books?id=EYHFObaUIdIC&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=who%20introduced%20mathematician%20to%20use%20first%20person%20plural&source=bl&ots=i_NUhXZmb6&sig=UJq-DP_bivx8kyAyE_u5Fvjn-Z0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a9ypUu-uMaSuyQHTr4HoCA&ved=0CGIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=who%20introduced%20mathematician%20to%20use%20first%20person%20plural&f=false) has a good book on writing mathematical prose) the most common reasons for using *we* instead of *I* are:

1. To emphasize participation by the reader and ensure that he or she is included.
2. To *not* sound egotistical. As in, to stress the mathematics and reduce the role of the author in particular.
3. To keep the writing in active voice.

I couldn't find when a the shift in writing style occurred, but I do recall reading [papers by Euler](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506415) in which he uses *I*. Though, I cannot read Latin and these were translated.